# onWindowFocusChanged except for dialogs

Tags: android, dialog, focus

I currently check to see if my activity's focus has changed via `onWindowFocusChanged()` (for example, the home button was pressed or it has switched to a different activity) and if it has, I call `finish()` on it. My problem is that I *only* want this to work in the event that the home button was pressed or another activity has been started using `startActivity()`, but something like a alert dialog can cause the focus to change and consequently finish the activity as well. How can I make the activity finish only when the home button was pressed or another activity has been started using `startActivity()`, and not when something like a dialog has appeared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `finish()` in `onStop()` that will destroy your `Activity` when it is no longer visible.  A standard dialog will only cause `onPause()` to be called.  Log the activity lifcycle events when they occur and you can check what operations trigger them.